# Julia: Use an older version of a package

Tags: julia

I am really new to Julia and confused about using an old version of the SISL [Vec](https://github.com/sisl/Vec.jl) package.

I am trying to setup [ngsim_env](https://github.com/sisl/ngsim_env) and [their instructions](https://github.com/sisl/ngsim_env/blob/master/docs/install_env_gail_full.md) require you to use an older [v0.1.0 of Vec](https://github.com/sisl/Vec.jl/tree/v0.1.0). But, when I followed the instructions to install the Vec package and then checkout the v0.1.0 tag it didn't work.

Here's what I did

1. `$ julia ../build.jl` for some package which includes this block

   `packages = keys(Pkg.installed())
   if !in("Vec", packages)
       Pkg.clone("https://github.com/tawheeler/Vec.jl.git")
   end`

Note: This git URL actually goes to the SISL Vec page.

2. `cd ~/.julia/packages/Vec
   git fetch tags
   git checkout v0.1.0`
3. I did a bunch of other installations with many other packages. At some point I noticed that there is a package `~/.julia/dev/Vec` and `~/.julia/packages/Vec`. The one in dev has the correct v0.1.0 code and the one in packages has the newer wrong code. When I tried to use other packages that needed the older Vec they were throwing errors and the paths were to files in the packages directory.
4. I tried `Pkg.rm("Vec")`. This did something to the project manifest. After nothing worked, every package would throw errors like `KeyError: key "Vec" not found` and `Pkg.add("Vec")` nor original Vec installation helped. I even tried removing both the Vec directories from `~/.julia` but that didn't help.

I guess a big question is why does Julia put some packages into `packages/` and others into `dev/` and how to control which one's get used if the same package appears in both places like Vec is.

Would greatly appreciate any assistance, totally confused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The dev command fetches a full clone of the package to ~/.julia/dev/

via [the docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Pkg/index.html#Developing-packages-1). The only things I have in my `dev` directory there are the ones I am developing on my own.

I think that triggered when you did a check out manually with git checkout.
Accordingly:

> to stop tracking a path and use the registered version again, use free

Try deleting the packages, and whipping mentions of `Vec.jl` from your manifest:

```
(v1.0) pkg> rm Vec
(v1.0) pkg> add https://github.com/tawheeler/Vec.jl.git@0.1.0
```

In general, try using `Pkg` when possible, cause it does a lot of house keeping magic in the back

(Also, the repl interface with `pkg` makes everything easier, so hit `]` from a blank `julia>` to get there. And a quick `Pkg.status()` or `] st` will show you what youre tracking and whats in dev and what version you have pinned, etc.)